# Saving has_many records on create of the belongs_to record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill
end
```

Then in my form I've got several fields for invoices all with the name `bill[invoice_names][]` so I can access them from `params[:bill][:invoice_names]`.

At the moment I've got a method like this on my Bill Model:

```
#bill.rb
def save_invoices(invoices)
  if invoices
    invoices.each do |invoice|
      @invoice = Invoice.new
      @invoice.invoice = invoice
      @invoice.bill_id = self.id
      @invoice.save
    end
  end 
end
```

And then call it on the create method of bills_controller like so:

```
#bill_controller.rb
def create
  @bill = Bill.new(params[:bill])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @bill.save
      @bill.save_invoices(params[:bill][:invoice_names])
      flash[:notice] = 'Bill was successfully created.'
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Since rails is often magical I tried naming the fields `bill[invoices][]` and crossed my fingers hoping it would just create those records at the same time with no extra code.  It didn't work so I wrote that `save_invoices` method, and had to rename the fields to something other than `bill[invoices][]` because that gave me an error.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [nested forms](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes). Introduced in Rails 2.3, I have seen [some criticism of them](http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2009/02/24/rails-23-nested-object-forms-im-not-crazy-about-them/), so make sure you read up and weigh the options.